# Gitorious on Dreamhost: Gemfile syntax error

Tags: ruby, passenger, gitorious

While trying to deploy "self hosted" Gitorious onto a Dreamhost shared hosting account, I get a syntax error in a Gemfile during the "bundle install" command:

```
$ bundle install --path vendor/bundle
Gemfile syntax error:
/home/<user>/git.<user>.org/Gemfile:33: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end
```

gem 'rugged', git: 'https://github.com/libgit2/r...
                  ^

Here's the Gemfile line that's choking:

```
gem 'rugged', git: 'https://github.com/libgit2/rugged.git', branch: 'development', submodules: true
```

The version of ruby is kind of old and some googling makes me think that might matter...

```
[footprint]$ ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [x86_64-linux]
```

Anyone have any ideas?  The closest I've been to troubleshooting Ruby anything is setting up some Puppet related stuff at work.  I'm not so sharp on this technology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes,

the second parameter on that line is a hash.

ruby 1.8.7 doesn't support the new hash notation
`a = { b: 1 }`

this is valid from ruby 1.9 and later.

for ruby 1.8.7 you need to format your hashes like:

`a = { :b => 1 }`

So in your case:

`gem 'rugged', :git => 'https://github.com/libgit2/rugged.git', :branch => 'development', :submodules => true`

should be ok.